# RECORRER JSONOBJECT, ANDROID

Tags: java, android, json

Necesito tomar los valores que estan dentro de REGION

```
"addresses":[{
            "id":2,
            "customer_id":2,
                "region":{
                    "region_code":"NY",
                    "region":"New York",
                    "region_id":43
                    },
                "region_id":43,
                "country_id":"US",
                    "street":[
                                "123 Oak Ave"
                            ],
                "telephone":"512-555-1111",
                "postcode":"10755",
                "city":"Purchase",
                "firstname":"Henry",
                "lastname":"Arcila",
                "default_shipping":true,
                "default_billing":true
        }],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"addresses" es una `JSONArray`, por lo tanto debes usar `json.getJSONArray("addresses")` para obtener el array para acceder a sus elementos:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("addresses");
JSONObject jsonRegion;
String region_code = "";
String region = "";
int region_id = 0;


for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    jsonRegion = jo.getJSONObject("region");
    region_code = jsonRegion.getString("region_code");
    region =jsonRegion.getString("region");
    region_id= jsonRegion.getInt("region_id");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No veo cuál es el árbol completo de ese objeto por lo que te doy una solución a partir de lo que has preguntado.

Si sacas el objeto `addresses[0]` a una variable y empiezas a parsearlo a `JSON` tienes que seguir estos pasos:

```
String region_code = "";
String region = "";
int region_id = 0;

try {
    JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(obj);
    JSONObject region= reader.getJSONObject("region");
    region_code = region.getString("region_code");
    region = region.getString("region");
    region_id = region.getInt("region_id");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Probablemente el objeto sea más largo y tengas que realizar el parseo de todo el objeto hasta llegar a este punto, pero sería repetir las acciones desde la raíz del objeto.